# Load Data In file MySQL MacOS

Tags: mysql, macos, csv

I'm trying to load data from a CSV using MySQL, but I'm getting Error code 29 (file not found). I'm using mac osx, but when I run the following query

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/workspace/SQL_Test/src/values.csv' 
INTO TABLE queryid_vs_column
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
```

MySQL tries to look in 'C:/workspace/SQL_Test/src/values.csv'. I haven't found anyone else with similar issues, has anyone encountered something like this? I'm not sure why MySQL thinks I'm running a windows machine.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `show variables like 'datadir';` ?

Comment: Is the MySQL server running on the Mac? `LOAD DATA INFILE` accesses files on the server, not the client.

Comment: Ahh okay, so does that mean `LOAD DATA LOCAL` accesses the client? @Barmar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't use the `LOCAL` modifier, it accesses the file on the server. Change your query to:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/workspace/SQL_Test/src/values.csv' 
INTO TABLE queryid_vs_column
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
```

Comment: Thank you. I see now this was a silly question, sorry for that.